# Why does MS-Access fire an Enter event for a Save record button when opening a form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, data-binding, vba

I have to process access and excel files from different departments in my MS-Access database.
The user must select these files, so I created a table of departments in which the user must fill in file names.

On the form to fill in these file names, I added a button to open a file selection dialog. 
[image]

I created this button as a Save Record button and put the logic in the `On Enter` event.
[image]

Now each time the user opens the form, the file selection dialog already opens for the first file, before the form is even shown.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

For completeness: this is my code for the Enter event:

```
Private Sub SelectCmd_Enter()
    On Error GoTo hell

    Dim FileDlg As FileDialog
'    If is_loaded Then
        Select Case Me.Controls("Filter")
            Case "Excel File"
                Set FileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
                FileDlg.Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls"
                FileDlg.InitialFileName = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\")) & Me.Controls("FileNameTemplate").Value
            Case "Access DB"
                Set FileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
                FileDlg.Filters.Add "Access DB", "*.accdb"
                FileDlg.InitialFileName = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\")) & Me.Controls("FileNameTemplate").Value
            Case "Folder"
                Set FileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
                FileDlg.InitialFileName = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\"))
        End Select
        FileDlg.Title = Me.Controls("Caption").Value
        If FileDlg.Show Then
            Me.Controls("FilePath").Value = FileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1)
        End If

        Set FileDlg = Nothing
'    Else
'        is_loaded = True
'    End If
    Exit Sub
hell:
    Debug.Print Err, Error
    Debug.Assert False
    Resume
End Sub
```

I tried solving the isue by setting a private boolean `is_loaded` to false when loading the form:

```
Private is_loaded As Boolean
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    is_loaded = False
    [...]
End Sub
```

but then the `SelectCmd` button on the first line did not react to clicks anymore when the file was loaded.

Comment: Please supply the code you have, expected result.

Comment: Why would you use the Enter event of a command button instead of Click event?

Comment: Thanks June7. With the Click event is works fine. If you can also explain why, please share your knowledge in an answer.

Comment: Most likely the button gets focus when the form opens. Possibly because its TabIndex property is set to 0.

Comment: @Dirk Horsten: This is by design. The `Click` event fires, when you click, and the `Enter` event fires when the related control receives the focus (actually, even before that). The online help says: `The Enter event occurs before a control actually receives the focus from a control on the same form.`

Comment: Indeed, June7, it is the only enabled control except for those in the footer, which I did not show.